# How to get date and time from user in google calendar API?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-calendar-api

I am using google API to create some events in google calendar. I need to get the date and time from the user input. This might be my logic issue but I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
var dateTime;

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    var date = req.body.date;  //I get date from user
    var time = req.body.time;  // I get time from user
    dateTime = date +'T'+ time+":00"; //trying to create the RFC3339 fromat
    console.log("date time: ",dateTime);
    createEvents(jwtClient);
  }); 

 var event = {    
  'start': {
      'dateTime': dateTime,
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
     'dateTime': '2020-06-12T12:00:00',
     'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },

 'conferenceData': {
    'createRequest': {
      'conferenceSolutionKey': {
        'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
        },
     'requestId': 'iyfuted65e3ers'

    }
  },

'attendees': [
  {'email': 'test@test.com'},
  {'email': 'jhfk@test.com'},
],
'reminders': {
  'useDefault': false,
  'overrides': [
    {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
    {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
   ],
  },
};


 //Create Appointment
  function createEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
    calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        conferenceDataVersion: 1,
        resource: event,
    }, (err, res) => {
       if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
         else {
        result = res.data.hangoutLink;
        console.log(result," start date: ", event.start.dateTime);

       }
    });
 }
```

when I print the dateTime in my post section it is the right date that user entered but it does not recognize it in event variable. and I get this error message:

**Error: Start and end times must either both be date or both be dateTime.**

I also have another question, how can I add an hour to start time and use it for end time?

[You can see the text fields that user can enter the date and time here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxpJp.png)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The RFC3339 formatted string expects the time in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

Sample how to convert time object in the format `hh-mm` into an RFC3339 formatted string:

```
  var date = req.body.date;  //I get date from user
  var time = req.body.time;  // I get time from user
  time = time.split("-")[0] + ":" + time.split("-")[0];
  var dateTime = date +'T'+ time+ ":00";
```

- Start and end times of Google Calendar events must be formatted according to [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)
- You can retrieve the time with [new Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)
- If you need to retrieve the client time zone and correct it manually to the desired timezone, you can use [getTimeZoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

I did not quite understand how you want to process the user time zone, but here are two samples showing what is possible:

```
  var now = new Date();
  Logger.log("Current time:" + now);
  var dateTime = new Date(now.getTime()).toISOString().split(".")[0];
  Logger.log(dateTime);
  var event = {    
   'start': {
      'dateTime': dateTime,
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
   'end': {
     'dateTime': '2020-06-12T12:00:00',
     'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
...
```

```
  var now = new Date();
  Logger.log("Current time:" + now);
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  offset = (offset / (-60));
  if (offset < 10) {
    offset =  '0'+offset;
  }
  offset = '+' + offset + ':00';
  var dateTime = new Date(now.getTime()-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000).toISOString().split(".")[0] + offset;
  Logger.log(dateTime);
  var event = {    
    'start': {
      'dateTime': dateTime
    },
   'end': {
     'dateTime': '2020-06-12T12:00:00-07:00'
   },
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I can see this will give me the current date and time but in my code I'm getting the date and time from the user in separate fields. How can I use the data that user entered in that field?

Comment: You can find the picture of data entry here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxpJp.png